# Управление шаговыми двигателями, схема подключения. От пк к двигателю

Tags: raspberry-pi, электроника

Хочу научиться управлять шаговыми двигателями, путем написания программы на Python. Пересмотрел кучу видео, но так и не понял.

Предположим есть 4 двигателя, рассчитываю все их задействовать в одной конструкции.

1. [Первый двигатель](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1781700551.html?sku_id=66176255921&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.7.78d54aa6I8KMDf)
2. [Второй двигатель](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32572890101.html?sku_id=65863360243&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.9.78d54aa6I8KMDf)
3. [Третий двигатель](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005003874936862.html?sku_id=12000027368897726&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.10.78d54aa6I8KMDf)
4. [Четвертый двигатель](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32377416566.html?sku_id=12000025791649821&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.14.78d54aa6I8KMDf)

На сколько понимаю, для каждого из двигателя необходим драйвер. Есть решение, где одна плата и 4 драйвера.

https://youtu.be/HrkFPEfovy4?t=392

Подскажите пожалуйста данную плату, где я могу найти ее, как она именуется?
Нашел что та похожее, не знаю подойдет? Самое доступное [На 5 осей](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32290989249.html?sku_id=66665970931&spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.20.75894aa6ykJGWt)

К данной плате мы подключаем уже 1 драйвер на 1 двигатель. Вопрос, двигатели совершенно разные, разные мощности, крутящие моменты и тп. Как узнать, какой драйвер подойдет для конкретно каждого из двигателя. Они универсальные? То есть все 4 драйвера одинаковые, то есть к одному драйверу возможно подключать любой двигатель, на характеристиках не скажется?

Затем мне потребуется [Пк](https://market.yandex.ru/product--mikrokompiuter-orange-pi-pc-1gb-h3-kabel-pitaniia-mini-pk-orandzh-pai-odnoplatnyi-kompiuter/1753869070?clid=1601&utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=ymp_offer_dp_dety_model_bko_dyb_search_rus&utm_content=cid%3A76579948%7Cgid%3A4998679028%7Caid%3A12577625668%7Cph%3A2783261%7Cpt%3Apremium%7Cpn%3A1%7Csrc%3Anone%7Cst%3Asearch%7Crid%3A2783261%7Ccgcid%3A0&cpa=1)

Получается, сперва пк -> плата -> драйвер -> двигатель.

Верны ли мои рассуждения? Сори, но даже не знаю какие теги мне к вопросу подкрепить.

Comment: может поучиться стоит на моторчиках полегче? https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005004901605615.html?spm=a2g2w.productlist.search_results.15.31655d6fNcKp31&sku_id=12000030958221104